Python 3.8 Compatibility Issue with MatLab 2021a
I tried everything but nothing worked out, if someone had this issue before and solve it, could you share your solution?
>> pyenv('Version', '/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/bin/python', 'ExecutionMode', 'OutOfProcess');

>> pyenv

ans = 

  PythonEnvironment with properties:

          Version: "3.8"
       Executable: "/Users/aliaaafify/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/bin/python"
          Library: "/Users/aliaaafify/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/libpython3.8.dylib"
             Home: "/Users/aliaaafify/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10"
           Status: NotLoaded
    ExecutionMode: OutOfProcess

>> py.importlib.import_module('sys')

Unable to resolve the name py.importlib.import_module.


You should not try to import modules, they are imported automatically when used.
For example, if you want to see the value of sys.copyright, in MATLAB you'd write
py.sys.copyright


still I get Unable to resolve the name py.sys.copyright.
Matlab already don't read any python command.

@AliaaAbdelnasser Did you specify the Python path correctly then? What does !/Users/aliaaafify/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/bin/python in MATLAB do?
